# Is it possible to get changes to an appointment?

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is it possible to get changes to a specific appointment with Exchange Webservices.
I would like to create an appointment with an outlookaddin and create a custom property with an id in it. 
Can I somehow get all changes of that meeting with exchange webservices?

And an extra question:
Is it possible to get the changes too if it is a meeting series and someone changes only the date of a single meeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EWS you can subscribe to notifications so you will get (or can query) when a particular item has changed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . However EWS doesn't track changes at the property level. If you want to do this you have to implement it your self eg store a copy of the current item, detect when it gets changed and then compare each property you want to track to detect the changes. With calendars also a change to recurring appointment will only mean a modification of the Master instance.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer i needed